# Windows Authentication and local DB user authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am using windows authentication impersonation in my MVC application.when i open the application the browser display a prompt for the credentials and validate the domain users.

But now i also want to create user in my application and also want to authenticate that users which is stored in my database.

Is it possible to authenticate Application DB users as well with windows authentication for domain users. i did much R & D on this but didn't found any solution yet. I will appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: IIS and ASP.NET are in general not designed for that kind of scenarios. You simply trouble yourself. But if you insist, one possible option is to 1) use forms based authentication 2) when authenticating users, query both AD and database to see if user credentials are valid or not. There you cannot use most of built-in classes by Microsoft, and have to write quite a lot custom code.

Comment: By default, Enable both windows authentication and custom user authentication is not valid. You have to manually handle the request from the domain and outside. check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963618/iis-mixed-anonymous-and-windows-authentication

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to allow both Windows Authentication and Forms Authentication. This is not a common thing to do, but I have done it. Here is how I did it:

You have to use forms authentication as your primary authentication. So build the Forms Authentication as you normally would: you have a login page that, after submitting, validates the credentials from your database. The tricky part is adding Windows Authentication.

To do this, create one action in your authentication controller that uses Windows authentication. For this example, I'll assume your controller is `AuthController` and we'll call the action `WinLogin`. That action will look something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult WinLogin() {
    var principal = HttpContext.User;
    if (principal == null || !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        //Windows authentication failed
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    // User is validated, so create the form authentication cookie
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(principal.Identity.Name, false);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

It just checks if the user is validated and, if so, sets the Forms Authentication cookie with their AD username.

For that to use Windows Authentication, you have to update your web.config to tell it to use Windows Authentication for only that one action. You do that with a `<location>` tag:

```xml
<location path="Auth/WinLogin">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

By default, IIS won't let you change the authentication method at this place in the config. You need to update the "Feature Delegation" in IIS Manager to allow it.

1. In IIS Manager, click the server name on the left.
2. On the right, double-click "Feature Delegation" under the "Management" section.
3. Change both "Authentication - Anonymous" and "Authentication - Windows" to "Read/Write".

If you use IIS Express for debugging, you have to do something similar for that:

1. In the project folder, open the file `.vs\config\applicationhost.config`.
2. Modify these two lines so they say `"Allow"`:

```xml
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Next update your login page to hide the username and password fields by default (let's say they are inside a box with an id of `loginBox`). The idea is that you perform an AJAX request to the `WinLogin` action, and if that succeeds, then you forward the user on to the main page or whichever page they were trying to go to. If you use jQuery, that will look something like this:

```js
$.get("@Url.Action("WinLogin", "Auth")")
    .done(function() {
        //success! forward to the page they want
        window.location.replace(returnUrl);
    }).fail(function() {
        //failed - show manual login prompt
        $("#loginBox").show();
    });
});
```

As long as your website is already a trusted website (which I assume so if you already have Windows Authentication working now), then the Windows Authentication will happen during that AJAX GET request.

Notice the use of [`window.location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace), which will not add the login page to the browser history, so if the user then hits the back button, they do not come back to the login page. It makes things a little more seamless.

You could also add a loading circle or something to indicate that the user should wait while that GET happens, but you can decide that.

With all this in place, the user experience should be:

1. They access a page.
2. They are not authenticated, so they get redirected to the login page.
3. The login page attempts the Windows Authentication in the background.
4. If the Windows Authentication succeeds, they are automatically redirected back to the page they wanted.
5. If Windows Authentication failed, the username and password boxes appear and they can login manually.